# Not converting to utf-8 in py2neo while iterating IterableCypherResults

Tags: python, py2neo

I am trying to retrieve some values from my neo4j database using py2neo

```
  query_results = neo4j.CypherQuery(graph_db,"START n=node(*) MATCH (n:Concept)  RETURN n.name, ID(n) ORDER BY n.name ASC LIMIT 200").stream()
  result = []
  for record in query_results:
    result.append({'id':record[1],'name':unicode(record[0]).encode("utf-8")})
```

This works fine in most of the cases, but fails when I have an n.name like "Hand-Schüller-Christian histiocyte (cell)"

```
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The error is thrown at the line "for record in query_results:" And the following errors are thrown in the py2neo source

```
 File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/py2neo/neo4j.py", line 1141, in __iter__
 yield self._record(*_hydrated(assembled(row)))

 File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/py2neo/neo4j.py", line 178, in _hydrated
 return type(data)([_hydrated(datum) for datum in data])

 File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/py2neo/neo4j.py", line 177, in _hydrated
 elif is_collection(data):

 File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/py2neo/util.py", line 134, in is_collection
 hasattr(None, obj)
```

I am not sure if its a py2neo bug or if am doing something wrong. Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code fails here:

```
unicode(record[0])
```

Why? Because when no encoding is specified, the `unicode` constructor expects the string encoding to be `ascii`. Basically, it expects something like:

```
unicode(ascii(record[0]))
```

Now, how do we get around this? Very simple! Just pass the `encoding` parameter - in your case it's `latin-1` - to the constructor:

```
unicode(record[0], encoding='latin-1')
```

See?

Here's a little demo:

```
>>> s = "Schüller"
>>> unicode(s, encoding='latin-1')
u'Sch\xfcller'
```

Edit:

After doing a bit more research, i think yes, this is a bug triggered by an unexpected byte sequence or character set in the query result. Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/nigelsmall/py2neo/issues/187).

However, looks like it's been fixed in the newer release, 1.6.1. Hope this helps!

Comment: actually its failing in this step "for record in query_results:". I think there might be a bug in the iterable method for IterableCypherResults in py2neo. So far, I cannot find a work around

Comment: Nah, nope. It's when you tried to convert non-ascii strings to unicode! The error is `UnicodeEncodeError`, right? :)

Comment: yup. But i get the error even if I comment the portion "  result.append({'id':record[1],'name':unicode(record[0]).encode("utf-8")})" .

Comment: Updated my answer, sorry about that

Comment: Updating the py2neo helped. Thanks :) I was using 1.6.0

Comment: Glad to hear that! Hahaha. Good luck with your project :)